# Which redirect (301 or 302) should we use for multilanguage website in OctoberCMS for SEO purpose?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have a multilanguage website Built on OctoberCMS and I have added translate component like this on layout.

```
[localePicker]
forceUrl = 1
```

Now it is redirecting with 302 status code. so I want to know is it correct way of redirecting for SEO purpose because I read that 301(permanent redirect) must be used for better seo ranking and 302(temporary redirect) should be avoided if possible.

Please help me into that

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

assuming the translated URL is different, I suggest leaving it with 302 itself so that Google indexes the URL variations. if 301, Google is only going to index the translated URL because of a permanent redirect.

Comment: do you mean if I use 301 then google will not index both urls (https://www.example.com/en and https://www.example.com/es is in my case). ???

Comment: If you use 301 redirect, it is permanent and the URL doing the redirect won't be indexed. In your case, if the user came to your site through example.com/en and was 301 redirected to example.com/es. Google will not index example.com/en